# Vim Error 'E212: Cannot open file for writing', when trying to create new files outside of home dir

Tags: debian, vim, root, vi, privileges

I am running Wheezy Debian. When I try to create a new file in a directory other than my home directory, such as `/var/www`, I get the following error in vim:

> E212: Cannot open file for writing.

I assume this is because I do not have the correct privileges to create files outside of my home directory?

My user account is in the sudoers file with `(ALL=(ALL) ALL)`, and I have administrator access.

I'm aware of tricks such as `:w !sudo tee %`, however this still results in a readonly file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I ended up solving the issue by changing the the folder owner to myself, using `chown`. This resulted in me not having to use sudo everytime I wanted to create/edit a file.

Comment: Please don't do that. There's a reason why those directories are protected. You _should_ use sudo every time you want to create a file, it's not that hard and it's worth it to keep your system secure.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I am not able to comment yet. Try to run command :`sudo -s` by this you will login as root. Then, I guess, you can do whatever work you want to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run vim as root.

```
sudo vim /var/www/file
```